# Drag an drop doesnt work in Xamarin Studio 6.3

Tags: xamarin

I have a problem in Xamarin Studio. I cant drag and drop elements into the layout phone, the element dissapears after i drag it from the toolbox. Im using Windows 10 and Xamarin Studio 6.3. Do you guys have any ideas what I can do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe XS is supported on Windows any more.

Comment: Everything else works..

Answer (score 0):

Since Microsoft has aqcuired Xamarin they immediately deprecated Xamarin Studio for Windows in favor of Visual Studio. Although you mag have found a working version, support has stopped. This means, that they will (probably) have stopped taking into account any compatibility with Xamarin Studio for Windows. Because of this the drag-and-drop functionality may have stopped working.

There could also be a number of other causes for this as well, but you are on your own finding it. Microsoft/Xamarin now wants you to use Visual Studio and are not likely to support the version you are running anymore.

Comment: I see, problem is that im using a laptop and Xamarin Studio is faster. Otherwise I would prefer Visual Studio because coding is more comfy

Comment: I agree! It was a lot more light-weight and I still favor using Xamarin Studio on the Mac rather than Visual Studio on Windows. You could check out Visual Studio 2017, it should be a lot more responsive. I see the [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/) branch is still here which should also support Xamarin, so you could look into that.

Comment: Weird, it's running better. Visual Studio it is for now!

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Studio is deprecated.
2 options - install Xamarin Studio 6.0.2 (prior the existence of this bug) or switch to Visual Studio with Xamarin enabled.

Original bugzilla reference with the latest official update - [link](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36689)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Xamarin Studio 6.1. And Laster. The only workaround is to downgrade to Xamarin Studio 6.0.